# CSV created with first row as empty. Any suggestions please

Tags: csv, contenttype

i am trying to create a csv and succeeded in that except with a new empty row has been added on the top of the csv. The following is the visualforce page code for the generation.

Also, i need to use the same page to create csv's for 2 to 3 custom list which are more or less have similar structure. What i used is nested if's to identify which content i need to output as csv and also to create headers. Is that a right approach using nested if's to handle different csv header structures in a single page?

**Any best approaches to create and download CSV?**

Is there any other best approaches available to generate and download csv's apart from the one simple method given below? Experts please advice.

```
     <apex:page StandardController="Account" extensions="OpenDocumentsController" contentType="text/csv#OSO_{!CustNo}.csv" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false">
            {!(If(CSVTab=='OSO','Order #, Document Date, Purchase Order #, Sales Org, Amount,Currency,Products',If(CSVTab=='OD','abcd','test')))}
         <apex:repeat value="{!OpenSalesOrders}" var="oso" rendered="true">
            {!oso.OrderNo},"{!oso.DocumentDateCSV}","{!oso.PurchaseOrderNo}","{!oso.SalesOrg}","{!oso.Amount}","{!oso.Curren}","{!oso.Product}"
         </apex:repeat>
    </apex:page>
```

**Screen shot with empty line at the top:**

[image]

Comment: On the white space, eliminate the line breaks in your Visualforce. Won't look pretty but should eliminate the spurious blank line.

Comment: You should make that an answer, Keith.

Comment: @JeremyNottingham Was put off by there being several other questions posed too - hopefully someone will write an answer that covers those.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> i am trying to create a csv and succeeded in that except with a new
>   empty row has been added on the top of the csv. The following is the
>   visualforce page code for the generation.

You need to make sure there's no intervening space between the opening page tag and the next tag:

```
<apex:page ...>{!output}</apex:page>
```

> Also, i need to use the same page to create csv's for 2 to 3 custom
>   list which are more or less have similar structure. What i used is
>   nested if's to identify which content i need to output as csv and also
>   to create headers. Is that a right approach using nested if's to
>   handle different csv header structures in a single page?

You're doing this in Visualforce expressions, which can be problematic, as larger files will take forever to export and may run into Visualforce runtime exceptions. I would recommend simply emitting a string directly, as in the prior example above:

```
public String getOutput() {
    String result = '';
    // Build csv headers and values
    return result;
}
```

Also, I've noticed you're probably not escaping the fields correctly (quotes within a field need to be double-quoted, as in `"""Bob's"" Bar-B-Que"` for `"Bob's" Bar-B-Que`).

You might be able to use a polymorphic method to generate your code to make the code easier to follow:

```
abstract class CSVBuilder {
    abstract String buildCSV(SObject[] records);
}

class OSOCSVBuilder extends CSVBuilder {
    override String buildCSV(SObject[] records) {
        // implementation 1;
    }
}

class ODCSVBuilder extends CSVBuilder {
    override String buildCSV(SObject[] records) {
        // implementation 2;
    }
}
```

Then, you can change your "getOutput" method:

```
public String getOutput() {
    SObject[] data = loadData(); // Some function that gets the data to output
    Map<String, Type> dispatch = new Map<String, Type> {
        'ODO' => ODOCSVBuilder.class,
        'OD' => ODCSVBuilder.class
    };
    return ((CSVBuilder)dispatch.get(CSVTab).newInstance()).buildCSV(data);
}
```

You can add new implementations by adding a mapping to the dispatch table, and implementing the subclass, as desired. You can source from some other data point if you like; it doesn't have to be a list of SObject records.

The base abstract class can also provide some utility functions, such as the proper escaping of field values, etc; you can use those those functions common to both classes directly using that manner.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. This is excellent notes and everyone should keep in their library as reference.